# indexOf(String) linked list char logic error

Tags: java, algorithm, linked-list, logic, indexof

First year CS student. Ive tried to implement an indexOf(String) method in my custom MyStringbuilder class (in this case with a linked list of char). I cant get the right output for finding the query string at the front or not finding it but anything in the middle of of the initial string doesnt work. Specific example below in my test driver.

```
public int indexOf(String str)
    {
        int index =-1; //index at which str is first found in linked list string of chars
        int count = 0; //num of matches
        int firstI = -1;
        int sI=0; // dynamic counter variable to allow str.length and for loop to interact
        CNode currNode = firstC;
        for (int i = 0; i < length; i++)
        {
            if (currNode.data == str.charAt(sI))
            {
                if (count < 1)
                    firstI = i;
                count++;
            }

            if (count == 0 && (sI == str.length()-1))
                sI=0;

            if (count == str.length())
            {
                index = firstI;
                break;
            }

            if (count > 0 && currNode.data != str.charAt(sI))
            {
                sI = 0;
                count = 0;
            }


            currNode = currNode.next; //increment
            sI++;
        }

        return index;
    }
```

TEST DRIVER CLASS

```
System.out.println("\nTesting indexOf method");
        b1 = new MyStringBuilder("who is whoing over in whoville");
        String s1 = new String("who");
        String s2 = new String("whoing");
        String s3 = new String("whoville");
        String s4 = new String("whoviller");
        String s5 = new String("wacky");
        int i1 = b1.indexOf(s1);
        int i2 = b1.indexOf(s2);
        int i3 = b1.indexOf(s3);
        int i4 = b1.indexOf(s4);
        int i5 = b1.indexOf(s5);
        System.out.println(s1 + " was found at " + i1);
        System.out.println(s2 + " was found at " + i2);
        System.out.println(s3 + " was found at " + i3);
        System.out.println(s4 + " was found at " + i4);
        System.out.println(s5 + " was found at " + i5);
```

Answer (score 0):

You don't set firstI anywhere inside the loop, but it ends up the value you return. This will always return -1.

Additionally, I think you might want to take another look at the variable sI, it doesn't seem to serve any real purpose. If count is ever != sI then you have an issue, so you could just get rid of sI completely.